# Ho w to scroll down vertically in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

i can able to scroll horizontal the data is coming in single line.But i what to do like that content should be come in like if the page border is going to end it should come in next line.  Can you please please on this.

Comment: Here i am pasting my code..div layout="row" layout-margin>
  <div  layout="row" ng-repeat="x in list " style="border: 2px solid black;margin:10px;text-align:center">{{x}}
   <a href=abc.html>
   <div flex ng-repeat="(y,z) in se[x] " style="border: 1px solid black ;margin:10px; ">{{y}}<br>{{z}}
   </a>
  </div>

Comment: I i need to scroll down..the page.In a line i have to keep 3 tables and remaining should come in next line...like that how can i do that..

Answer (score 0):

Not getting what you really want to ask? Ng-repeat will work fine.